# Triple Boot Issue with Ubuntu, Kali and windows

Tags: dual-boot, bootloader, kali

Okay, I am in a slightly *very bad* situation here. 
As of last week my laptop was running both Ubuntu and Windows perfectly. Then I wanted to install Kali Linux, and I did the same. While installing Kali, my computer hanged while installing the boot loader. So I just shut it down.

Now problem 1, when I restarted it, it went straight into grub rescue. I found the partition for Ubuntu/ bootloader and deleted the Kali partition and updated my grub from Linux. But in the boot options the option 'kali' was always there. I just didn't seem to care about it.

All was fine, until today, when I was working in Ubuntu, I try to view the system monitor when suddenly my system crashes telling me Kali boot has been updated. 
When I restart the same, it went straight to Kali boot loader, with no sign of ubuntu. When I enter into Kali Linux, it takes me to Ubuntu but does not go in. It displays the message "your computer is running in low grpahics and input devices cannot be accessed. You have to configure them manually". When I took a bootable USB and checked the partitions from it, I noticed that in the partition /dev/sda6 which was Ubuntu first, is now being recognized as Kali.

My windows is booting perfectly and I have a bootable USB with Ubuntu. I want the data in Ubuntu, atleast someone give me a way for that. Thanks._/_

P.s I am not able to add pictures as this is my first attempt at using this website and I don't have any reputations. Thanks again!

Comment: Run boot-repair app or its live cd/usb. Google it, it should help fix your issue. That app has never failed me for situations like this.

Comment: Hi thanks, but I just tried boot repair twice and it doesn't seem to solve the problem! :/

Comment: Do you have a separate /boot partition? It sounds like what may have happened with problem 1 was that while you deleted the kali partition, you left the kali kernel in /boot, which grub recognized as a valid linux kernel.

Comment: @Aargonian yeah i do have a seperate partition. Now I am trying to access files in Ubuntu using windows ext4 explorer. If i am able to that, I plan to delete the entire remaining stuff and start afresh!